# PHP Mailer senders email is the same as the recipient

Tags: php, forms, phpmailer

I am new to PHP and I am making a page where I have form on it. When the client fills all of the information from the input fields and clicks submit I am receiving a mail. The problem that I am facing is that even though I am entering different senders email address on the form , when I click the submit btn , the mail in my inbox  that I am receving it turns out to be from me ( i.e. like I am sending it to myself -even though there is a different senders email address on the form). I have tried everything I really do not know where my problem is. In here I am using $$$ because I am hiding my real info.
Here is my code

```
<form action="send-mail.php" method="post">
            <div class="b-form__inputWrap">
                <label for="name">Name</label>
                <input name="name" id="name">
            </div>

            <div class="b-form__inputWrap">
                <label for="email">email</label>
                <input name="email" id="email">
            </div>

            <div class="b-form__inputWrap">
                <label for="name">Subject</label>
                <input name="subject" id="subject">
            </div>

            <div class="b-form__inputWrap">
                <label for="name">Message</label>
                <textarea name="message" id="message" name="message" placeholder="enter message"></textarea>
            </div>

            <button class="b-form__btn" type="submit" name="submit">Send</button>
        </form>
```

PHP

```
         <?php
         error_reporting(E_ALL);
         ini_set('display_errors', 1); 

         use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
         use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

         require 'vendor/phpmailer/phpmailer/src/Exception.php';
         require 'vendor/phpmailer/phpmailer/src/PHPMailer.php';
         require 'vendor/phpmailer/phpmailer/src/SMTP.php';

         if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
         try {
         $mail = new PHPMailer(true);

         $mail->isSMTP();
         $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
         $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
         $mail->Username = '$$$$$$$$$$';
         $mail->Password = '$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$'; 
         $mail->SMTPSecure = PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_SMTPS;            
         $mail->Port = 465;   

    
         $mail->setFrom($_POST['email']);
         $mail->addAddress('$$$$$$$$$$$$$');
         $mail->addReplyTo($_POST['email']);
    
         $mail->isHTML(isHtml:true);

         $mail->Subject = $_POST["subject"];
         $mail->Body = $_POST["message"];

        $mail->send();
        echo 'Email sent successfully!';
       } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo "Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: {$mail->ErrorInfo}";
     }
    }


      ?>
```

Comment: `$mail->setFrom($_POST['email']);` - sets sender from form and `$mail->addAddress('$$$$$$$$$$$$$');` sets to where send email and I guess it's your email. Switch in place these values.

Comment: `$mail->addReplyTo($_POST['email']);` is also email from form

Comment: Form labels, except for `email` points to `name` input element

Comment: $mail->addAddress($_POST['email']);
     $mail->setFrom('$$$$$$$$$$'); you mean like this. because this is making me to send email from me to the one that is written in the input

Comment: This is how it looks in my email :
from: mymail@gmail.com
reply-to: sendersmail@hotmail.com
to: mymail@gmail.com
This is wrong, the from email needs to be the email from the input that the client has written, not my email.

Comment: No, you will have issues if sender does not match actual user of SMTP. `from` must be same as in `$mail->Username`. You can not send emails from different `from` as it's security issue and most providers does not allows it. Image I send you email `from = info@your_bank_name.com` - very wrong!

Comment: I do not get it , I have a contact us form on my page. And when the client clicks on the submit btn I want to receive a mail from them(from the form). I do not want to send them mail . Also this   $mail->Username = 'mymail@gmail.com'; and this  $mail->setFrom('mymail@gmail.com') are the same in my code; Do you understand what do  I mean?

Comment: @ilhan's answer is correct, as per [the PHPMailer docs on this subject](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting#dont-forge-from-addresses). gmail will not let you send as anyone but yourself (and predefined aliases); other `From` addresses will be ignored. The right way is to follow [the contact form example provided with PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/contactform.phps).

Comment: In this case I need to use another SMPT and not Gmail. What others SMPT do you recommend so I can achieve what I want?

Comment: @mp89 You can not. It's security issue.

Comment: Think about it...what you're trying to do is impersonate someone else's account. You can't do that without their login credentials for their email account. If anyone could spoof anyone else's email address easily there would be chaos (and we know this because security used to be a lot more lax and malicious parties used to impersonate emails much more freely, leading to all sorts of phishing and other security issues). Just make the email from a fixed account put the email address from the form into the message body and/or the reply-to header, as per your needs

Answer (score 2):

You are logging in to Gmail as $$$$$$$$$$ (your own address). Why would they allow you to seem like you are sending from some other address?

It is a security measure. Gmail will not let you do this.

Workaround: Append their email address at the end of their text.

Comment: In OP code `$$$$` are placeholders (I hope)

Comment: I have used $$$$ here because I am hiding my real email in here. In my original code I am using my valid email

Comment: I used placeholder too :)

Comment: This answer is correct; upvoted.

Answer (score 1):

As already said, many e-mail servers, including Gmail, will not let you send e-mails as someone else. This is to protect Google (or any other host) from being banned by other servers for sending spam and malware.

And that's for a reason. If you can say you are someone, who filled form, then just as good you can say you are president of USA. 99% of internet users don't know how to check it, and even, if they do, usually they don't check every mail they see.

But even, if you have your own server, where you can set sender without any problem, it is not a good idea. Most servers verifies, who is sending e-mail. For example, of you are trying to send mail as john@example.com from IP 123.456.12.34 they will ask domain example.com if it can send mails from that IP (if you want to know more, google for SPF). If it does not, they will just delete such mail as it's almost always malware, and probably will ban this IP address for at least few days and even add it to some blacklist, so other will ban this IP too.

What you can do is to set repply-to address ((but even this can be blocked) or just you can add this mail somewhere in message body, like "user with mail xxx@yyy.com send following message:[br][message goes here]".

But try to say you are not you, this is just asking for trouble.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. I have switched to Brevo and it works fine for now.
Do you think that the safest way for my problem  is that there is a user created i.e I mean a userprofile with valid information?

Comment: I don't know how they have configured their server on Bravo, but generally if you have control over domain and server, it's only important to have sender from same domain, user does not have to exist there. If you don't, receiver should not block you, but your mail server can, since it can check if your "from" mail is set to same as your login points out. 

And some servers care much about what you are sending, because once their IP is blacklisted, every other user using their server (with same external IP) gets blacklisted, and that can be big problem sometimes.